# There is a line $l$ with parametric vector equation $\vec r=\vec r_0 + t\vec s$, a point $P$ and its position vector $\vec r_P$.

Tags: geometry

Let point $M$ be a orthogonal projection of point $P$ onto line $l$. How to find the position vector $\vec r_M$ of point $M$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vector from $M$ to $P$ is $r_P - r_M$, it should be perpendicular to the line, which has direction vector $s\ne 0$:
$$
s \perp (r_P - r_M) \iff \\
0 = s \cdot (r_P - r_M) \quad (*)
$$
on the other hand $M$ is on the line, thus
$$
r_M = r_0 + t s \quad (**)
$$
for some value $t$. We insert $(**)$ into $(*)$ and get
$$
0 = s \cdot (r_P -(r_0 + ts))
= s \cdot (r_P-r_0) - t s^2  \iff \\
t = \frac{s \cdot (r_P - r_0)}{s^2}
$$
which we insert into $(**)$ to get
$$
r_M = r_0 + \frac{s \cdot (r_P - r_0)}{s^2} s
$$

Answer (score 0):

Find the value of $t$ for which $r_P-r$ is perpendicular to the line. Therefore $$(r_P-r_0-ts)\cdot s=0$$ which gives $$t=\frac{(r_P-r_0)\cdot s}{s^2}$$

Then plug this value into the equation of the line.